# Why is Mobx 6 behavior different between my two environments?

Tags: mobx

I'm migrating a store to Mobx 6 in our TypeScript code base.  This store is shared between a React web component, and an Expo React Native component.

It looks like this:

```js
class MyStore {
  value: string;

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {value: observable});
  }
}
```

This works fine for my React web component.

However, when I use this in my Expo React Native component, I get this error:

```
[MobX] Cannot apply 'observable' to 'MyStore@2.value': Field not found.
```

If I initialize `value` to null before calling `makeObservable`, everything works fine.  But don't like how the behavior is different between our web component and our mobile component.  This will likely be the source of bugs in the future if I can't get them both to behave the same.

Any idea what is causing this behavior, and why this behavior might be different between the two environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one of the [limitations](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#limitations) of `make(Auto)Observable` if you haven't setup your compiler with [additional options](https://mobx.js.org/installation.html#use-spec-compliant-transpilation-for-class-properties). So probably one of your projects have different setup than the other.

**TypeScript**: Set the compiler option `"useDefineForClassFields": true`.

**Babel**: Make sure to use at least version 7.12, with the following configuration:

```
{
    "plugins": [["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": false }]],
    // Babel >= 7.13.0 (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/assumptions)
    "assumptions": {
        "setPublicClassFields": false
    }
}
```

Usually it is better to call `make(Auto)Observable` as the last thing in constructor, and/or define properties right away. For example in your case just define it with empty string (it is more correct even because your current code won't compile in `strict` mode anyway):

```
class MyStore {
  // No need for explicit type that way
  value = '';

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {value: observable});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I removed the typescript "useDefineForClassFields" compiler option on my web project, and now both environments behave the same.  They both require the fields to be initialized now.  Thanks!