# Mobx observer change not triggering rerender in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mobx, mobx-react

I have been stuck at this for a long while now and I am not sure what exactly to do here

I have two components

`Navbar.tsx`

```js
import CoreButton from "../../core/CoreButton";
import {observer} from "mobx-react-lite";
import accountStore from "../../store/account.store";

function Navbar() {

    const onClick = () => {
        accountStore.login();
    }
    return (
        <header>

            <CoreButton
                onClick={onClick}>
                Do stuff
            </CoreButton>


        </header>
    )
}

export default observer(Navbar)
```

And a `Hero.tsx`

```js
import CoreButton from "../../core/CoreButton";
import {observer} from 'mobx-react-lite';
import accountStore from "../../store/account.store";
function Hero() {


    return (
        <section>

            <CoreButton>
                {accountStore.address}
            </CoreButton>

        </section>
    )
}

export default observer(Hero)
```

and I have mobx store

```js
import {configure, makeAutoObservable} from "mobx";

configure({
    enforceActions: 'never',
})

class AccountStore {
    address: string | undefined;
    isLoading: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    login() {
        this.address = "Hello World";
    }

}

const accountStore = new AccountStore()
export default accountStore;
```

So when I click on "Do Stuff" Button on the Navbar I am expecting the text in the Hero to change

But this is not happening. I tried to do this with redux-toolkit and It worked. Does mobx just not work with Next JS or am I missing something here.

P.S. I am not trying to do any sort of data fetching here, Mobx Store will be used while the user is interacting with the application and be reset on refresh

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Mobx 6 behavior different between my two environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70291989/why-is-mobx-6-behavior-different-between-my-two-environments)

Answer (score 0):

it was because of

```
address: string | undefined;
```

For some reason mobx doesnt like `string | undefined` so I changed it to

```
address: string = '';
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

**A better solution is:**

```
address: string | undefined = undefined;
```

Or:

```
address?: string = undefined;
```

You don't need to set wrong data to make it work.

You just need to set initial value even if it is undefined,
this makes MobX initiate the variable in the memory and deal with it afterwards.